# Pass raw html for button into column of jquery datatable from controller

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, datatables

I have a controller that returns a generic `DataTable` to a View.  I want to display this table as a `jquery` datatable.  One of the columns has an html button in it, so far just a string:

```
<button class='editbtn'>edit</button>
```

The jquery datatable displays it just like that instead of displaying a clickable button.  When I view page source I see that the special chars have been escaped:

```
<td>&lt;button class=&#39;editbtn&#39;&gt;edit&lt;/button&gt;</td>
```

Is there anything I can do to have this display as a button?  Remember, I am not using `ajax`, just passing a `DataTable` from a controller to a view, here is the table in my view:

```
<table id="onHandDataTable" class="display compact row-border cell-border hover tablefont">
            <thead>
        <tr>
            @foreach (DataColumn col in Model.Columns)
            {
                <th>@col.ColumnName</th>
            }
        </tr>
    </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (DataRow row in Model.Rows)
                {
                    <tr>
                        @foreach (DataColumn col in Model.Columns)
                        {
                            <td>@row[col.ColumnName]</td>

                        }
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

And here is the javascript for datatable:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var table = $('#onHandDataTable').DataTable({
        "iDisplayLength": 100,
        "lengthMenu": [[25, 50, 100, -1], [25, 50, 100, "All"]],
        "oLanguage": {
            "sSearch": "Filter Results: ",
            "sLengthMenu": "Entries per page: _MENU_",
        },
    });

});
```

Comment: "One of the columns has an html button in it," . So your data has html markup for a button ? Why ? why not render the button inside the razor table rendering code ?

Comment: You can use `Html.Raw` so that razor will not encode HTML, as needed

Comment: Yes my data has html markup for a button.  I guess because im not sure how to do that.

Comment: ill look into Html.Raw, thanks

Comment: You can set that as the answer and ill mark it right, it worked perfectly, thank you.  Idk how i looked everywhere and never found that.

Comment: Did you know you're using the outdated legacy version of datatables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Html.Raw is an option;
I'm wondering why the button is in the Columns in the first place? 
If you're setting it in the controller, don't; 
Using Html.Raw on the whole table open you up to html injection

Instead you could set it up in the .cshtml, something like this

```
            <tr>
                @foreach (DataColumn col in Model.Columns)
                {
                    <td>@row[col.ColumnName]</td>
                }
                <td><button class='editbtn'>edit</button></td>
            </tr>
```

.. you will might want to add a th to the table header too.